Using pytorch/torchtune without GPU and CPU only
Im trying to use pytorch/torchtune without GPU and CPU only.
from tutorial ive installed torch with this command :

pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio


and for torchtune ive used this one to install it :
pip install torchtune


and when ive going to use finetune command like this :
tune run lora_finetune_single_device --config llama3/8B_lora_single_device


im getting this error :
RuntimeError: The local rank is larger than the number of available GPUs. 

Im using VSCODE as programming environment
followed https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ tutorials

from the docs, it sounds like you can add something like device="cpu" at the end of your command line call.

always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.
